# timer error in c programming for Linux operating system?

Tags: c, linux, timer, timertask

```
struct timeval begin, end;
double begin_time, end_time, timer_count;

void deadline(int t){

    if (t > 0){ 
        fprintf(stdout, "t= %lf\n",t);
        gettimeofday(&begin,NULL);
        timer_count = t;
        begin_time = (begin.tv_sec) * 1000 + (begin.tv_usec) / 1000 ;
        return begin_time;
    }
    else{ 
        fprintf(stderr, "Please pass only zero and positive values\n");
        return;
    } 
}

void deadline_one(){
    double diff;
    fprintf(stderr, "Sec \n");
    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
    end_time = (end.tv_sec) * 1000 + (end.tv_usec) / 1000 ;
    diff = end_time - begin_time; 
    fprintf(stdout, " diff = %lf end_time = %lf begin_time =%lf\n", diff,end_time, begin_time);

    if (timer_count >= diff){
        fprintf(stdout, "These set of lines takes %lf milliseconds to execute\n",diff);  
        while(timer_count >= diff){
            gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
            end_time = (end.tv_sec) * 1000 + (end.tv_usec) / 1000 ;
            diff = end_time - begin_time;
            fprintf(stdout,"diff = %lf\n",diff);
        }
    }
    else{
        fprintf(stdout, "These set of line takes more then %lf milliseconds to   execute\n",timer_count);
        fprintf(stdout, "These set of lines takes %lf milliseconds to execute\n",diff); 
    } 
}
```

I want a begin_time and end_time in a double format. I am using `gettimeofday` API for calculating it.
I am doing it for Linux operating system. The above code is printing 0 value for begin_time, end_time and diff between the begin_time and end_time. Could someone please tell me what is the error in the above code?

Comment: You need a cast to double or you lose precision:`end_time = (end.tv_sec) * 1000 + (double)(end.tv_usec) / 1000 ;`. Same thing for begin_time of course.

Comment: Please edit your question and either remove the 'linux-kernel' tag, or explain why it is relevant to the question.

Comment: Read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) then use [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html), casting appropriately to `double` as suggested by other comments!